# How to update Organization Policy of a "No Organization" project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to migrate a "No Organization" project into my new Organization.

It was blocked by constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations, which is set to Deny All.

I tried to assign myself (project owner) a Organization Policy Admin role, but that role is not available on project level.

That means I can't migrate my project at all.

What should I do?

Comment: Is your project one created by a Google Partner? If yes, you will need to open a support ticket to disassociate your project from their account. If this is a project that you created yourself via the Google Cloud UI, and you have the Owner role, the constraint should not exist.

Comment: Have you already checked [Configure organization policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration?hl=en#configure_organization_policies) and [Project move permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration?hl=en#assign_permissions). See also [Migrating projects with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration?hl=en#special_cases)

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. It turns out that the projects are falsely represented as "No Org" because the previous Cloud Identity org was renamed and I lost all the access. This was a separate issue outlined in https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Security/Cloud-Identity-to-Workspace-issue/m-p/436780#M343.

Comment: How did you regain control?

Comment: I haven't regain control. The Cloud Identity org was renamed to "xxxxxx.appstempdomain.goog" and I still haven't found a way to access it.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer then?

Comment: The answer is one of the problems I encountered. My question turned out to be a compound of various issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the Super Admin of the destination org to the project and proceed with the constraints of the destination organization. The Super Admin has the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#assign_permissions) to proceed with the migration. You should configure the Organization [policies](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#configure_organization_policies) on the parent resource to the project you want to move, set an organization policy that includes the `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedExportDestinations` constraint. This will define the target destination as a valid location to which you can migrate the project.

On the destination resource, set an organization policy that includes the `constraints/resourcemanager.allowedImportSources` constraint. This will define the source as a valid location from which you can migrate your project.